# How can I transfer apps from one profile to another on my tablet?

Tags: multi-user

I have just bought a tablet to be used by the whole family.  I downloaded some apps and games, and then set up two more users. Neither have, nor want, a Google account. (In fact our son is too young for a Gmail account according to Google.)

I am completely new to Android, as I have a Windows Phone and Windows computers so please go easy on me.  I have a Wikipad with Android 4.2 Jelly Bean.

The apps I downloaded all appear on my user/profile and there is very little on my son's or my husband's (not even all of the pre-loaded ones, it would appear).

Do I need to download them all again for each user/profile or is there a way of making them show up?  One of them (a Flight Simulator game exclusively for my son) was a paid-for app.

Comment: I am on Android 14 but the answers below do not work for me. I also want to install some apps on my child's profile but I do not want to create a gmail account for him in order to access the Play Store. Is it possible to simply copy the app from the administrator profile to the child profile?

Answer (score 1):

From the Admin/Owner account, go to Settings > Users > (user name) > Apps, click the little cog next to the restricted account, and you will see all apps permissions. You can give access to whichever app you like.

If you don't know if you are using Admin/Owner account, just head into Settings > Users. Under one user name would be shown "Admin" or "Owner".

Answer (score 1):

If this is about a Child profile, login as the Admin/Owner account, go the Settings > Parental controls > Household profile > Manage child's profile > Add content > Share content, and then select whichever apps you want to share.

If you don't know if you are using Admin/Owner account, know that if you are not using a restricted profile / child profile, than you are already logged in as the Admin.