# Samsung Tab S6 Lite saying "Not Enough Space" when I try to switch storage to SD card for apps in a non-administrator user account

Tags: applications, sd-card, permissions

To add to what the title says, I have no problem when I am in the user account on the Samsung Tab S6 Lite to switch apps that are coded for such to be on the SD card that I have installed in this tablet.  It works just fine.

But, when I log into one of the other user accounts on this tablet that is not the administrator, the system says "Not Enough Space" when I try to move one of the apps in that user account over to the SD card.

It is obviously some permissions issue but I cannot figure it out after spending time going through all sort of menu options.

Google search was not great for this.  One thing similar along this lane but different is this here:
[How can I transfer apps from one profile to another on my tablet?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/103774/how-can-i-transfer-apps-from-one-profile-to-another-on-my-tablet)

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.